# Why is it possible to switch the two variables in this set of partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

The following is from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999176900073).

$y_i$ is a set of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) with $t$=time and constants $c$.

$\dot{y_i} = f_i(y_1, ..., y_n, t, c) = f_i(y, t, c)$. [1]

To get the parameter sensitivities for a system of ODE's we introduce $n$ new variables that measure the sensivity of parameter $c$ to variables $y_i$

$Z_i = \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial c}$           [2]

These are found as the solution to $n$ new differential equations $\dot{Z_i}$.

$\dot{Z_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(Z_i) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial c})$ [3]

So far so good. What I don't understand is why the following holds:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial c}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial c}(\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t})$ [4]

Is there a rule in calculus that I'm missing that allows one to switch the variables like this? Or perhaps its just algebra? Either way, could somebody help me understand why [4] holds true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Comment: If you know that the mixed partial derivates exists and are continuous, you can exchange the order. This makes no assumption about the (total) derivative of the function.

If you know that the given function posseses (total) derivative of order $k,$ then all mixed partial up to order $k,$ inclusive, commute.